# what is difference between '%[^0-9.-]%' and '%[^0-9]%' in regular expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

Can someone please explain for what reason we use .- in the regular expression and what is difference between '%[^0-9.-]%' and '%[^0-9]%'

Comment: What do you not understand?  They have different character sets and it looks pretty clear what the differences are.

Comment: usage of  .- in this expression

Comment: Perhaps better - _what do you understand_ about each individual expression? Then clarity can be shown.

Comment: In conjunction with `NOT LIKE` One of them looks for strings only containing digits. The other one looks for strings only containing digits, decimal point or minus sign. Or that will be the intent anyway. It depends on collation what exactly the `0-9` range matches

Comment: The suggested duplicate isn't relevant because it doesn't apply to SQL Server

Comment: yaa what will be the difference in results if I use these expressions becaue I can't see any difference in results when I used

Comment: Please consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) before asking the community.

Comment: @AbhishekTandon the differences have been stated, but perhaps if you show us some of the results for each expression then we can further verify what the expressions are doing. As it stands you haven't provided much context nor example cases.

Comment: @DaleK I voted when the question had a regex tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%[^0-9.-]%` will include period '.' and dash '-' characters, while `%[^0-9]%` will not